# calling another function in getJSON in JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
function myFunction(param)
{
    $.getJSON('/url', {'param':param}, function(data)
    {
        confirm(data);
    });
}
```

i have a problem when calling myFunciton, the response function
do everything except calling another function like (confirm)

i call myFunction as a click event for button and the ajax request is sent correctly,
and when i change some global variables in the response function it is ok
The Main Problem in calling another function

for details
the real function

```
function display (gameid,index)
{
  $.getJSON('/games/play.json', {'game':gameid,'index':index,'data':'X'},function(data)
  {
    confirm(data)
    if(data=="X_Win")
    { 
       gameEnded=true;
       $("#result").innerHTML="You won";
    }
    else if(data=="Y_Win")
    {
       gameEnded=true;
       $("#result").innerHTML="You Lost";   
     }
 }
```

the gameEnded is set to true 
but the confirm() and $("#result")  >>> both not called

can any one help me.

thanks in advance
 M.SH

Comment: Provide more details. Are you getting any errors? How are you calling myFunction and are you sure you are actually executing it. Does the AJAX call successfully completes, etc ...

Comment: if (confirm('Are you sure')) ... r u trying to do like this??

Comment: i add some datails ,
 and i try if(confirm("")) and set a global i found it "false"

Comment: Within the callback function that you pass to `$.getJSON()` you can do anything that you'd do in any other function, including calling other functions _assuming they're in scope_. (I wouldn't name your function `confirm` though, given there's already a built-in [`confirm()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm).) Please show the definition of your other function.

Comment: i call the built in confirm() function

Comment: But the code shown isn't doing anything with the result of `confirm()` - there's not much point asking the user to select OK or Cancel if you don't do anything with the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of json, by appending url with `callback=?`

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/vX2YQ/2/)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can't call confirm function cause you'r in the callback of the getJson function.
It means that your not in the same context anymore.

You need to do this :

```
    function myFunction(param)
{
    $.getJSON('/url', {'param':param}, $.proxy(function(data)
    {
        this.confirm(data);
    }, this));
}
```

Comment: could you show me the definition of your other function / script file

Comment: i am now trying the confirm() function , not call any other

Comment: for better understanding of your error, it's better to show us more code